# How can I pass in multiple answers into openssl shell command?

Tags: openssl

When I run `openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem` it prompts me for several answers (address, name, country code etc...). When this is inside of a script how can I pass in these answers?

This:

```
RUN echo "something" | openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
```

Only answers the first question, but then the command fails since it didn't get any other answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it the `-subj` argument to which you can pass the details

```
-subj "/C=US/ST=STATE/L=CITY/O=ORG_NAME/OU=OU_NAME/CN=CN_OR_FQDN_OR_SERVER_NAME"
```